# Proof variance from mean and overall are not covaried?

Tags: probability-theory, sampling-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables
having variance $\sigma^2$

Show that $Cov [X_i − \bar{X},X] = 0$

So I get that $E[X_i - \bar{X}] = 0$, so all I'm left with proving is that $E[X_i − \bar{X},X] = 0$.

*Here we assume that* $X$ *is $\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$*

Comment: What is $X$ here?  One of the $X_i$?  Or their sum or  average?

Comment: Not specified. I would assume their sum because that's how we've seen it used thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that covariance is bilinear. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X_i − \bar{X},X)
&=\text{Cov}(X_i,X)-\text{Cov}(\bar{X},X)\\
&=\sum_j\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)-\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\sum_j\text{Cov}(X_j,X_i)\\
&=\sigma^2-\frac{1}{n}(n\sigma^2)=0\tag{1}.
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that the $X_i$ are independent and hence uncorrelated in (1).

Answer (score 0):

So you want $C=E((X_j-X/n)X)$, where $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, where the $X_i$ are iid $N(0,1)$.   Well, $C= E(X_jX)-E(X^2)/n = \sigma^2 - n\sigma^2/n = 0$.  Because $EX_j X = E X_j^2$ and because $X\sim N(0,n\sigma^2)$.